# CentOS 7 Terminal Timeout

Tags: linux, terminal, gnome-terminal

This seems like this question should have already been answered, but I don't see any info on google or stackoverflow. I have a VNC server running on a CentOS 7 box where I do my development. Every night my terminals timeout and die unless they have an active command running on them.  I have looked for configuration options to prevent this from happening but cannot find anything.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

P.S. This is not a ssh terminal session. It is a normal terminal session started on the box itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind. I'm an idiot. It's the unix $TMOUT variable. I just need to:

`unset TMOUT`

or

`set TMOUT=0`

Comment: In case anyone cares. My TMOUT was getting set in `/etc/profile.d/local.sh`